# Up to date gwt-incubator jars for Maven

Tags: java, maven-2, gwt

I want to use the latest gwt-incubator drop - gwt-incubator-july-14-2009.jar - in a Maven project.

The most recent version published on central is [1.5-Dec_28](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gwt/gwt-incubator/).

Is there a more up-to-date maven repo for the gwt-incubator jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of all the places, I found it at http://dist.codehaus.org/mule/dependencies/maven2/com/google/gwt/gwt-incubator/.

Answer (score 0):

The july-14-2009 version of gwt-incubator has recently (17th September 2009) been released  to the [maven.xwiki.org](http://maven.xwiki.org/externals/com/google/gwt/gwt-incubator/) repository.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've looked into it but it's even more out of date - see http://gwt-maven.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mavenrepo/com/google/gwt/gwt-servlet/ .

Comment: well that's no help at all then, sorry. I'll have a further look, but the Dec version is the latest on at least 5 repositories